# How to turn an array of paths into a multi dimensional array of varying depth?

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to turn an array of paths such as this:

```
$foo = [
 'a/b' => 1,
 'a/c' => 2,
 'x/y/0' => 4,
 'x/y/1' => 5
]
```

into a multi dimension array like that looks like this:

```
$foo = [
 'a' => [ 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2],
 'x' => [ 'y' => [0, 1]
]
```

The array of paths can contain any depth of path, and either be key value pairs or normal array accessed by index.  I've tried with recursion, but can't quite figure this out, even though I have a feeling the solution will be pretty short.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happened to the `4` and `5` values? Shouldn't the `x` key end with `[4, 5]` so `0=4` and `1=5`?

Comment: 'x/y/0' => 4 and 'x/y/1' => 5 implies that the value of 'x' => 'y' => is an array, not a map/key-value pair.  Talking about this kind of thing makes me wish those 2 things had different names in PHP instead of them both being called 'array'

Comment: but then what happened to the `4` and `5` values in `'x/y/0'` and `x/y/1`? They just disappear and no longer exist in the suggested output. How would `x/y/0/test` be treated? Also, you do realize that if you were to json_encode the output, an array with contiguous numeric keys starting at zero gets converted to a JS array, not an object (`[]`, not `{}`). If all you want to do is lose the value (right side of `=>`) and make the last value in the key the value appended to the output you could just do that in the below code. It is a simple test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without recursion using references to move deeper (and create new keys) into the output array. Something like this would work:

```
function nest($arr){
    //our output array
    $out = array();

    //loop over the array and get each key/value
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        //split the key
        $k = explode('/', $k);

        //create our first reference
        $tmp = &$out;

        //loop over the keys moving deeper into the output array
        foreach($k as $key){
            //if the key is not found
            if(!isset($tmp[$key])){
                //add it
                $tmp[$key] = array();
            }
            //get a reference to the sub-array
            $tmp = &$tmp[$key];
        }

        //here $tmp should be as far down the array as the value needs to be
        //set the value into the array
        $tmp = $v;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/unQukp